# Curl Request in .NET

Tags: c#, curl

I'm making the following CURL request in .NET as given below.

**Curl:**

```
curl -XPOST https://api.domain.com/v1/OTP/1234-5678-9012/ss123.123 \
-d "private=aaaa-bbbb"
```

**.NET:**

```
string url = "https://api.domain.com/v1/OTP/1234-5678-9012/ss123.123";
string data = "{\"private\"=\"aaaa-bbbb\"}";

WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
myReq.Method = "POST";
myReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();

using (Stream ds = myReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    ds.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
}

WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But I am receiving method not supported error, what am i missing?

Comment: Your json is wrong is should look like: `{\"private\": \"aaaa-bbbb\"}`

Comment: You should paste the stack trace too.

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify ContentType = json ? Your post request doesn't look like to be proper json ! Also, try to add a "Accept" header along the ContentType.

Comment: Can u refer point 3 here - http://dial2verify.com/mOTP_Missed_Call_OTP_Authentication/Documentation.html

Comment: @Richard  This is the PHP code                                                                      `// get login otp that was sent to user
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.motp.in/v1/OTP/YOUR_API_KEY_HERE/" . $reply["Result"]);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"private=YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE");
$replye = curl_exec($ch);
$reply = json_decode(trim($replye), true);`